# Div not expanding to 100% (default behaviour)

Tags: css, html, width

I have a strange problem....

Div should expand to 100% of available space by default, but its not the case.

I don't understand what's going on, even if I put display:block it's behaving as automatic width (relative to content).

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/T3arP/

The effect I need to achieve is let the box with green border absoluted or fixed to top of its container, so you can scroll keywords but title will remain there.

Comment: Maybe I should add overflow: auto only to keywords... would be easier dont you think?

Comment: Which div are you trying to make 100%?  Dark green border or light green border?

Comment: Light green, lol you have a good eye. The other is like black for me :P

Comment: When you absolutely position stuff, it breaks out of its container. Set the position of the container to relative, then set the width of the green box to 100%;, that should keep your box contained within the larger div, and make it expand to the full width of its parent.

Comment: When setting `position: relative`, there is no need to set `width: 100%` - that might make it expand too much - see http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you absolutely position something (that's using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`) `width: auto` no longer expands it to the container's width. The rules from which the width is actually determined are complicated*. That's why many people consider it a good practice to set a specific width on those elements (absolutely positioned ones, that is).

*you can find out about those rules at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I usually do.

Answer (score -1):

As has been said, once you absolutely position an element, it loses the parent's tag association in a sense.  So you could do something like this maybe.

http://jsfiddle.net/T3arP/1/